# Is there any alternative for type alias in C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++03

I want to create an alias `arr` for `std::array<T, 32>`.

```
template<typename T>
using arr = std::array<T, 32>;
```

However, it does not work on GCC 4.4.6 which supports only C++0x(without type alias).

I think it is a very bad idea to use GCC 4.4.6 now, however, I want to know if there are some ways to simulate **type alias**.

The following code may work, but `arr` is not precisely `std::array<T, 32>`, so I want a better solution.

```
template<typename T>
struct arr : public std::array<T, 32>;
```

Comment: " which supports only C++0x" note that `std::array` is also C++11

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I mean C++0x is a incomplete version of C++11, it has `std::array`, but no type alias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before alias templates were a thing, it was common to write this instead:

```
template<typename T>
struct arr {
    typedef std::array<T, 32> type;
};
```

Instead of `arr<T>` you would have to use `arr<T>::type` and `typename arr<T>::type` when `T` is a template parameter.

Comment: Of note this solution works in any C++ Standard, so code that needs to be Standard or Compiler agnostic (eg.: library code) should always be using this instead of ``using``.

Comment: @LuisMachuca `std::array` is C++11

Comment: I mean the more general technique of using ``sometype<Args>::type``, not array specifically, but point taken. (Even then, array is near trivial to backport to C++03 or even C++98)